# how to get data from mysql (last to first order) and Display in JSON php?

Tags: php, mysql, json

This is my Php file:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM sample";

$r = $conn->query($sql);
$result = array();

while($row = $r->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){

   array_push($result,array(
   "title"=>$row->title
    ));
}
echo json_encode(array('result'=>$result));
```

This code fetches the data from my database and displays from first to last order, but I need to create a reverse order (from last to first). Please help.

Comment: use `order by columnname desc`

Comment: Thanks @PavneetSingh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `SELECT * FROM sample ORDER BY ID DESC`

**ID** is the column, according to which you want to order.

Comment: ya I will try Thanks :)

Comment: Yup ;-) Works, Thanks!!

Comment: Yes I have voted but it takes 6 mins as count, so waiting. Don't worry I will mark as Correct ;-}

Answer (score -1):

Add `ORDER BY` and your column name in your query, followed by `DESC` or `ASC` (descending or ascending, the latter being the default). For example:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM sample ORDER BY title DESC";
```

Comment: ya I will try Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks @AravindVenkat Another thing: you can rewrite your `array_push` call as: `$result[] = ["title" => $row->title];` for short. Not sure why my answer was down voted though.